# The type LocalSessionFactoryBean is deprecated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-orm

I am using  spring-boot 1.4.2 for my simple project.When i insert LocalSessionFactoryBean to the database configuration class then it show "The type LocalSessionFactoryBean is deprecated".Is this spring-boot version problem.I'm tried to find that.But i couldn't find clear answer for this.Please help me.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE will fetch spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar if you have `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` in your pom.xml. If you check spring-orm jar file, it bundles `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3`, `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4` and `org.springframework.orm.hibernate5` packages for hiberante orm. From these packages `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean` is deprecated. You can check the details [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html). For LocalSessionFactoryBean for hibernate4 see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html) and for hibernate5 see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have that warning because you imported `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean` into your class.
[deprecated warning snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z4Ya.png)

To get rid of the deprecated warning import either
`org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean` or `org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean` into your class.
[deprecated warning gone snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrEUa.png)

Answer (score 1):

Check your imports, it should be:

```
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
```

or this one:

```
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
```